# Transcrypt and TranscryptFrame

Tags: transcrypt

Right now I am working on a wrapper for common functions for transcrypt called TranscryptFrame. I get a compiler error and I like to know if we can solve this in any way, maybe it is just a little change in the code to get things working.

You need to have the latest TranscryptFrame.py file in the working directory for compiling. You find it here: https://github.com/bunkahle/Transcrypt-Examples/blob/master/dom/TranscryptFrame.py - please feel free to suggest changes or improvements on this file or bug reports. It might be available sometime as a library in the future.

So here is the code which doesn't even compile, I get the error can't assign to function call.

```
# change_text2a_tf.py
import TranscryptFrame as tf

def insert():
    # working:
    # myElement = tf.S("#intro")
    # tf.S("#demo").innerHTML = "The text from the intro paragraph is " + myElement.innerHTML

    # working:
    # myElement_htm = tf.S("#intro", "htm")
    # tf.S("#demo").innerHTML = "The text from the intro paragraph is " + myElement_htm

    # working:
    # tf.S("#demo").innerHTML = "The text from the intro paragraph is " + tf.S("#intro", "htm")

    # not working: can't assign to function call on compiling
    tf.S("#demo", "htm") = "The text from the intro paragraph is " + tf.S("#intro", "htm")
```

and this is the html for running it:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="__javascript__/change_text2a_tf.js"></script>
    <title>Change Text with TranscryptFrame</title>
  </head>
  <body onload=change_text2a_tf.insert()>
    <p id="intro"><b>Hello World!</b></p>
    <p>This example demonstrates the <b>getElementById</b> method!</p>
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
tf.S("#demo", "htm") = "The text from the intro paragraph is " + tf.S("#intro", "htm")
```

you are assigning something to the result of a function, namely to `tf.S("#demo", "htm")`

This isn't possible in Python, JavaScript or Transcrypt. It is possible in C++ by returning a reference, but C++ is rather unique in that.

A function in Python, JavaScript or Transcrypt does not return an LValue (location in memory) but an RValue (the value that resides in that location).
You can't store anything in a value, only in a location.

The following piece of C++ code uses references and a function call to the left of a =:

```
float &lowestGrade (float &x, float & y) {
    return x < y ? x : y;
}
```

It can be called as follows:

```
grade1 = 4;
grade2 = 6;
lowestGrade  (grade1, grade2) += 2;
```

Note that `grade1` will be 6 after this.

But as said, functions returning LValues (locations in memory) are rather unique for C++.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the shortest way to do it would be:

```
tf.S("#demo").innerHTML = "The text from the intro paragraph is " + \
                           tf.S("#intro", "htm")
```

If I wanted something JQuery like:

```
$("#demo").html("The text from the intro paragraph is ")
```

I would need to call the pragma for JQuery like:

```
__pragma__ ('alias', 'S', '$')
S("#demo").html("The text from the intro paragraph is ")
```

and import the JQuery library in the html document with

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The only way to have something like

```
import TranscryptFrame as tf
tf.S("#demo").html("The text from the intro paragraph is ")
```

would be to to program a class named S or with a different name maybe like D (for document) so that I could handle it object-like with tf.D("#demo").html(*args). But since JQuery already exists it doesn´t really make any sense to implement a class in TranscryptFrame but just use the pragma and the existing JQuery library like:

```
__pragma__ ('alias', 'S', '$')
S("#demo").html("The text from the intro paragraph is ")
```

Comment: Maybe you could use Python / Transcrypt properties here to obtain an elegant notation. Assigning to the property would then call a function that would call JQueries .html (<aText>) method.

Comment: How would an elegant notation look like in your opinion? JQuery notation is quite short and quite effective. Maybe there would be a more pythonic style but I have no clue at the moment how it could like. I tried to implement functions like tf.doc_id(idname) in TranscryptFrame but they are still quite long in comparision to JQuery.